# PHP generates confusing output

Tags: php, html, forms

i'm trying build a table that has a delete button for every entry, but the output is confusing me. The code is as follows:

```
                    if ($players != null) {

                        echo('<table class="playerTable">');
                        echo('<thead>');
                        echo('<tr>');
                        echo('<th> Last Name </th>');
                        echo('<th> First Name </th>');
                        echo('<th></th>');
                        echo('<th></th>');
                        echo('</tr></thead><tbody>');

                        for ($i=0; $i<count($players); $i++) {
                           printf('<form action="player.php" method="post" onSubmit="return submitCheck(\'%s\', \'%s\')">', $players[$i]->name, $players[$i]->surname);
                           echo("<tr>");
                           printf("<td> %s </td><td> %s </td>", $players[$i]->surname, $players[$i]->name);
                           echo('<td><input type="hidden" name="delete" value="'. $players[$i]->id .'"></td>');
                           echo('<td><input type="submit" value="Delete"></td>');
                           echo("</tr>");
                           echo('</form'); 


                        }
                        echo('</tbody></table>');
                    }
```

For some reason that i don't get, the produced output is as follows:

```
<tbody>
<form action="player.php" method="post" onsubmit="return submitCheck('someName', 'someName')"></form>
<tr>
    <td> someName </td>
    <td> someName </td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="delete" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Delete">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Which leads of course to the fact, that the submitCheck won't be executed - what am I missing here?

Comment: Ok you told us how the output should `not` look like, care to mention how it `should`?

Comment: just make a string by appending all these things and echo it at last , then it will work

Comment: Sure, the <form> tags should embrace the whole <tr>, but it seems that php is not following the order of my echo-statements

Comment: In echo('</form'), you have to close the tag : echo('</form>');

Comment: This is invalid HTML. `<form>` tags are not allowed inside `<table>,<tbody>,<tr>,<th>,<thead>`. Put it before `<table>` or inside `<td>`.

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your HTML code. Also your code is not valid (but PHP generates it as it should (with table and th tags))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't have a `<form>` tag within a `<table>`. Make it the other way around. Also, in your opening `<form>` tag, there's a missing `=` sign at the action attribute. The end tag of `<form>` should also be outside of the `<table>`.

Comment: Do you care to elaborate? I have no idea how I would make it the other way round without losing the reference to the correct entry

Comment: You can start by reading the comments above. You can't put whatever element you think of inside of `<tbody>`. Put it inside the `<tr>` and update your output

Answer (score 0):

There is no `=` in `action"player.php"`
Try `action="player.php"`